# Prevent user from changing input method

Tags: android, android-input-method, device-admin

Is it possible to prevent a user from changing input method/keyboards?

I know it's not allowed by default but maybe with some security/IT device administration feature it is possible?

I've been looking around but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the search I performed suggests - there is no such way to prevent users from changing input method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some constraint that, this specific EdiText wont must raise a special type of keyboard (number pad / text) to type in. Add the following parameter in the EditText block **layout/xyz.xml**.

```
android:inputType=""//your specific type gies here e.g "number" "textUri" ...
```

details

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="142dp"
android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
android:ems="10" android:inputType="number">
```

you can also change it from the **properties** view by selecting appropriate EditText.

Comment: Thank you I know this one. I actually meant prevent the user from changing keyboard in the settings, like change default device keyboard

Comment: You may wanna use some java reflection, but it would be different for different os version (most probably ) :)